# How does data flow work when using the Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, fetch

Take a simple API fetch call, such as follows:

```
fetch('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=xxxxxxxxx')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data =>setPic(data.hdurl))
```

I'm still a bit confused about how this works. My understanding is this - information is sent from the web server as JSON, but to displayed on a web page it has to be converted into a normal JS object. Is this correct?

And if so, how does the above method convert JSON to a JS object? Because as I understand it, `res.json` simply extracts the JSON, it doesn't convert it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json: _“The json() method of the Body mixin takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise that resolves with the result **of parsing the body text as JSON**.”_

Comment: _"but to displayed on a web page it has to be converted"_ It does not _**have**_ to be converted to an Object to be displayed. If you want to show a JSON String to your user, you can do it. It only needs to be parsed if you actually want to manipulate its individual properties, such as `hdurl`

Answer (score 1):

> [...] how does the above method convert **JSON** to a **JS Object**? Because
> as I understand it, `res.json()` simply extracts the **JSON**, it doesn't
> convert it.

This is what `.json()` does - it resolves the **JSON string** and parses it into a **JS Object**:

```js
// Retrieves data from a URL
fetch('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,%7B%22myJSON%22%3A%20%22myJSON%22%7D')

// Resolve the data retrieved from the URL as JSON and parse into a JS Object
.then(res => res.json())

// Work with the resolved data
.then(data => {
  console.log('data has been resolved as: ' + typeof data);
  console.log(data);
});
```

If you want the **JSON String** to remain a **JSON String**, you can use `.text()` instead:

```js
// Retrieves data from a URL
fetch('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,%7B%22myJSON%22%3A%20%22myJSON%22%7D')

// Resolve the data retrieved from the URL as a string
.then(res => res.text())

// Work with the resolved data
.then(data => {
  console.log('data has been resolved as: ' + typeof data);
  console.log(data);
});
```